# Ethereum client - minimum for sending transaction

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, parity

Requirement:

- Reliably send Ethereum transactions
- Be connected to main nodes directly (speed)

Limitations:

- Disk size (20-40 GB)

Given this, what is the recommended configuration to run an ethereum node?

`geth --fast` Takes too much space. So does `parity --pruning fast`.
`geth --light` only connects to light clients and therefore is not entirely reliable.

`geth --warp` Gets you to a point where you can send transactions in a few GBs of space but the blockchain does keep syncing and eventually takes too much space.

Suggestions? What is actually required for an ethereum node to send transactions?

Comment: For anyone wondering, i eventually went with `parity --pruning fast --warp --no-ancient-blocks`. Seemed like the most reliable option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are your options:

- `parity --light` 3~5 MiB disk space
- `geth --syncmode light` 100~200 MiB disk space
- `parity --pruning fast --warp --no-ancient-blocks` 3~5 GiB disk space
- `parity --pruning fast --warp` 12~20 GiB disk space
- `parity --pruning fast --no-warp` 12~20 GiB disk space
- `geth --syncmode fast` 20~30 GiB disk space

All are connected to full nodes and enable you sending transactions reliably.

Comment: Do transaction behave entirely the same in these light modes? i.e. there's no advantage to running a node will full history?

Comment: also, i prefer to avoid the parity light mode as it's marked as experimental. Also not sure if it's the same as geth light mode, where it is running a special light client that also connects to light clients (not full clients)